# How to update props in Child when updating states in parent in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a React app with several components and APIs. I have a Parent component which is connecting with an API. I have a child component which has a popup modal which displays the API data. I created the modal inside the child component and calling it inside the parent component when API data is received. Now I'm updating this with Material UI Circular Progress to avoid the less usability of delaying the API response.

I'm calling the API in parent component and initially setting a state called isLoading as true. Within the API success method, I'm setting the isLoading to false. Meanwhile, I open the modal in the child component and send the isLoading state as a prop with API data. In the child component, I'm receiving these props. Initially, I'm getting isLoading as True and set a state as True. Then I'm waiting for false when API success in the parent, but **the problem is even after the API success, I can't get the updated isLoading (false) from parent to the child instantly. However, it is updating in a render function and I can get projectAllData. I just can't set states with updated isLoading in ComponentDidMount**

Parent:

```
class Taskboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      projectAllData: undefined,
      open: false,
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  getPojectId = (projectId) => {
    this.setState({ open: true })

    API.get('project/' + projectId)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({
          projectAllData: data.response,
          isLoading: false,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
      })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      {
          this.state.open ?
            <ProjectModal
              handleOpen={this.state.open}
              handleClosed={this.handleClose}
              projectData={this.state.projectAllData}
              isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
            /> : null
        }
    )
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class ProjectModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            single: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       this.setState({ single: !this.props.isLoading? this.props.projectData.currentAssigneeName : '' }) 
       //Initially this is True and is not updating when isLoading is False
    }

    render() {
      return(
         {
           this.props.isLoading ?
             <CircularProgress/>
           :
           <Modal />
         }
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: where you are calling `getPojectId` function.

Comment: the props in child will update when the state in parent changes.

Comment: @AmolBJamkar By another prop receiving from another child

Comment: you can use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#componentdidupdate) or [`static getDerivedStateFromProps()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Comment: @JuniusL. Currently it is not updating in ComponentDidMount. I'm not sure that where to put the setState to get updated prop

Comment: When your parent component updates the prop, for setting it inside your child you should use `componentWillUpdate`.
Because `componentDidMount` works only when the component mounts for the first time.

Comment: you need to update `open: true` in `this.setState` after API call success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` only gets called once, that is after initial render. For your usecase you need `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.isLoading !== prevProps.isLoading) {    
    this.setState({ /* here goes you state update*/ })
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't need those cycle methods.

Comment: yes of course the other option would be `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)`

Comment: you don't need all this just assign the value in render, usually a child component doesn't need state, you pass props and the child just display the data.

Answer (score 1):

First time only you get parent values in componentDidMount after that you will get in ComponentWillReceiveProps.If the API response is late so you can't get values in componentDidMount so in child component we have to call ComponentWillReceiveProps hook method. I will give example below.

```
ComponentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   this.setState({
       single: !nextProps.isLoading nextProps.projectData.currentAssigneeName : '' 
       }) 

}
```

we can also prefer static getDerivedStateFromProps instead of ComponentWillReceiveProps

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps ` is deprecated already, I wouldn't suggest it

Comment: if it's not preferable we can go with static getDerivedStateFromProps method

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution here, you don't need state, since it's not going to change, just set the value of single in render.

```
class ProjectModal extends Component {

    render() {

      const single = !this.props.isLoading 
        ? this.props.projectData.currentAssigneeName 
        : '';

      return(
        { this.props.isLoading 
          ? <CircularProgress/>
          : <Modal />
        }
      )
    }
}
```